# Error installing nokogiri: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: linux, terminal, nokogiri

I want to execute the following command

```
bundle install && rake install
```

but an error comes up and I try to figure out whats going on. I found that i need to install nokogiri. But when I try to install it an error comes up again. Any ideas? :/

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.5'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20181210-12550-orku3c.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.3.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.5
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.8.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.8.5/gem_make.out
```

Comment: It says you're missing zlib so you need to figure out which package that is for your system and install it.

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear enough. I have to do what?

Comment: For ubuntu try: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`